# React-Table with nested arrays, can't access the nested content

Tags: node.js, reactjs, datatable, nested, react-table

I am new to node/react/etc. and having trouble with a data table.

I am using the react-table module and I need to get the following structured data:

```
[
   {
      "document_id":"487375348",
      "organization_id":null,
      "doc_content":[
         {
            "PM":"test",
            "BOC":"0100",
            "COR":"test",
            "POC":"test",
            "TEST Ends":"2020-08-08T05:00:00.000Z",
            "Cost Pool ":"Summary Row",
            "Initiative":"test",
            "Budget Year":2020,
            "Commitments":345354,
            "Expenditure":345354,
            "Obligations":534534,
            "Projections":1231,
            "Project Code":"6212",
            "Service Manager":"test",
            "Card Holder Name":"test",
            "Date of Purchase (Service/Goods)":"2020-05-12T05:00:00.000Z"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "document_id":"487375349",
      "organization_id":null,
      "doc_content":[
            "PM":"test",
            "BOC":"0100",
            "COR":"test",
            "POC":"test",
            "TEST Ends":"2020-08-08T05:00:00.000Z",
            "Cost Pool ":"Summary Row",
            "Initiative":"test",
            "Budget Year":2020,
            "Commitments":34524,
            "Expenditure":346654,
            "Obligations":534334,
            "Projections":12322,
            "Project Code":"6213582",
            "Service Manager":"test",
            "Card Holder Name":"test",
            "Date of Purchase (Service/Goods)":"2020-05-12T05:00:00.000Z"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

into a table similar to:

```
Document ID     PM     CORS    FY XX Budget (Next Year's Budget)
[data]        [data]  [data]               [data]
[data]        [data]  [data]               [data]
[data]        [data]  [data]               [data]
[data]        [data]  [data]               [data]
```

I am using the sample example found here with a few changes:

```
import namor from 'namor'

const range = len => {
  const arr = []
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    arr.push(i)
  }
  return arr
}

const newPerson = () => {
  const statusChance = Math.random()
  return [{"document_id":"487375348"+ namor.generate({ words: 0, numbers: 2 }),"organization_id":null,"doc_content":[{"PM":"test","BOC":"0100","COR":"test","POC":"test","FALSE":false,"BFAF #":"33-3333","Budget":34535,"Office":"test","Vendor":"test","__EMPTY":false,"POP Ends":"2020-08-08T05:00:00.000Z","__EMPTY_1":false,"__EMPTY_2":false,"__EMPTY_3":false,"__EMPTY_4":false,"__EMPTY_5":false,"__EMPTY_6":false,"__EMPTY_7":false,"__EMPTY_8":false,"__EMPTY_9":false,"Cost Pool ":"Summary Row","Initiative":"test","POP Begins":"2020-05-05T05:00:00.000Z","Budget Year":2020,"Commitments":345354,"Expenditure":345354,"Obligations":534534,"Projections":1231,"Project Code":"6212","Cost Sub-Pool":"Summary Row","Service Owner":"test","Funding Source":"S&E","BOC Description":"INCOME - WCF","Contract Number":"23424","Service Manager":"test","Card Holder Name":"test","Procurement Type":"MOU","Comments / Changes":434,"Requisition Number":"23434","Servicing Agency/Bureau":"test","Total Balance Available":-846150,"Date of Purchase (Service/Goods)":"2020-05-12T05:00:00.000Z","FY XX Budget (Next Year's Budget)":"1999-08-08T05:00:00.000Z","Remaining Bal (Obligations - Expenditure)":189180,"Requestor (If not the same as Purchase Card Holder)":"test","Subtotal Remaining Bal (Budget - Obligations-Commitments-Projections)":-846584},{"PM":"test","BOC":"0100","COR":"test","POC":"test","FALSE":false,"BFAF #":"33-3333","Budget":34535,"Office":"test","Vendor":"test","__EMPTY":false,"POP Ends":"2020-08-08T05:00:00.000Z"},
{"document_id":"487375348"+ namor.generate({ words: 0, numbers: 2 }),"organization_id":null,"doc_content":[{"PM":"test","BOC":"0100","COR":"test","POC":"test","FALSE":false,"BFAF #":"33-3333","Budget":34535,"Office":"test","Vendor":"test","__EMPTY":false,"POP Ends":"2020-08-08T05:00:00.000Z","__EMPTY_1":false,"__EMPTY_2":false,"__EMPTY_3":false,"__EMPTY_4":false,"__EMPTY_5":false,"__EMPTY_6":false,"__EMPTY_7":false,"__EMPTY_8":false,"__EMPTY_9":false,"Cost Pool ":"Summary Row","Initiative":"test","POP Begins":"2020-05-05T05:00:00.000Z","Budget Year":2020,"Commitments":345354,"Expenditure":345354,"Obligations":534534,"Projections":1231,"Project Code":"6212","Cost Sub-Pool":"Summary Row","Service Owner":"test","Funding Source":"S&E","BOC Description":"INCOME - WCF","Contract Number":"23424","Service Manager":"test","Card Holder Name":"test","Procurement Type":"MOU","Comments / Changes":434,"Requisition Number":"23434","Servicing Agency/Bureau":"test","Total Balance Available":-846150,"Date of Purchase (Service/Goods)":"2020-05-12T05:00:00.000Z","FY XX Budget (Next Year's Budget)":"1999-08-08T05:00:00.000Z","Remaining Bal (Obligations - Expenditure)":189180,"Requestor (If not the same as Purchase Card Holder)":"test","Subtotal Remaining Bal (Budget - Obligations-Commitments-Projections)":-846584},{"PM":"test","BOC":"0100","COR":"test","POC":"test","FALSE":false,"BFAF #":"33-3333","Budget":34535,"Office":"test","Vendor":"test","__EMPTY":false,"POP Ends":"2020-08-08T05:00:00.000Z"}]
}

export default function makeData(...lens) {
  const makeDataLevel = (depth = 0) => {
    const len = lens[depth]
    return range(len).map(d => {
      return {
        ...newPerson(),
        subRows: lens[depth + 10] ? makeDataLevel(depth + 1) : undefined,
      }
    })
  }

  return makeDataLevel()
}
```

and here:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import {
  useTable,
  usePagination,
  useSortBy,
  useFilters,
  useGroupBy,
  useExpanded,
  useRowSelect,
} from 'react-table'

import makeData from './makeData'

const Styles = styled.div`
  padding: 1rem;
  table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    tr {
      :last-child {
        td {
          border-bottom: 0;
        }
      }
    }
    th,
    td {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0.5rem;
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
      border-right: 1px solid black;
      :last-child {
        border-right: 0;
      }
    }
    td {
      input {
        font-size: 1rem;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        border: 0;
      }
    }
  }
  .pagination {
    padding: 0.5rem;
  }
`

// Create an editable cell renderer
const EditableCell = ({
  cell: { value: initialValue },
  row: { index },
  column: { id },
  updateMyData, // This is a custom function that we supplied to our table instance
  editable,
}) => {
  // We need to keep and update the state of the cell normally
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(initialValue)

  const onChange = e => {
    setValue(e.target.value)
  }

  // We'll only update the external data when the input is blurred
  const onBlur = () => {
    updateMyData(index, id, value)
  }

  // If the initialValue is changed externall, sync it up with our state
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setValue(initialValue)
  }, [initialValue])

  if (!editable) {
    return `${initialValue}`
  }

  return <input value={value} onChange={onChange} onBlur={onBlur} />
}

// Define a default UI for filtering
function DefaultColumnFilter({
  column: { filterValue, preFilteredRows, setFilter },
}) {
  const count = preFilteredRows.length

  return (
    <input
      value={filterValue || ''}
      onChange={e => {
        setFilter(e.target.value || undefined) // Set undefined to remove the filter entirely
      }}
      placeholder={`Search ${count} records...`}
    />
  )
}

// This is a custom filter UI for selecting
// a unique option from a list
function SelectColumnFilter({
  column: { filterValue, setFilter, preFilteredRows, id },
}) {
  // Calculate the options for filtering
  // using the preFilteredRows
  const options = React.useMemo(() => {
    const options = new Set()
    preFilteredRows.forEach(row => {
      options.add(row.values[id])
    })
    return [...options.values()]
  }, [id, preFilteredRows])

  // Render a multi-select box
  return (
    <select
      value={filterValue}
      onChange={e => {
        setFilter(e.target.value || undefined)
      }}
    >
      <option value="">All</option>
      {options.map((option, i) => (
        <option key={i} value={option}>
          {option}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  )
}

// This is a custom filter UI that uses a
// slider to set the filter value between a column's
// min and max values
function SliderColumnFilter({
  column: { filterValue, setFilter, preFilteredRows, id },
}) {
  // Calculate the min and max
  // using the preFilteredRows

  const [min, max] = React.useMemo(() => {
    let min = preFilteredRows.length ? preFilteredRows[0].values[id] : 0
    let max = preFilteredRows.length ? preFilteredRows[0].values[id] : 0
    preFilteredRows.forEach(row => {
      min = Math.min(row.values[id], min)
      max = Math.max(row.values[id], max)
    })
    return [min, max]
  }, [id, preFilteredRows])

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="range"
        min={min}
        max={max}
        value={filterValue || min}
        onChange={e => {
          setFilter(parseInt(e.target.value, 10))
        }}
      />
      <button onClick={() => setFilter(undefined)}>Off</button>
    </>
  )
}

// This is a custom UI for our 'between' or number range
// filter. It uses two number boxes and filters rows to
// ones that have values between the two
function NumberRangeColumnFilter({
  column: { filterValue = [], preFilteredRows, setFilter, id },
}) {
  const [min, max] = React.useMemo(() => {
    let min = preFilteredRows.length ? preFilteredRows[0].values[id] : 0
    let max = preFilteredRows.length ? preFilteredRows[0].values[id] : 0
    preFilteredRows.forEach(row => {
      min = Math.min(row.values[id], min)
      max = Math.max(row.values[id], max)
    })
    return [min, max]
  }, [id, preFilteredRows])

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: 'flex',
      }}
    >
      <input
        value={filterValue[0] || ''}
        type="number"
        onChange={e => {
          const val = e.target.value
          setFilter((old = []) => [val ? parseInt(val, 10) : undefined, old[1]])
        }}
        placeholder={`Min (${min})`}
        style={{
          width: '70px',
          marginRight: '0.5rem',
        }}
      />
      to
      <input
        value={filterValue[1] || ''}
        type="number"
        onChange={e => {
          const val = e.target.value
          setFilter((old = []) => [old[0], val ? parseInt(val, 10) : undefined])
        }}
        placeholder={`Max (${max})`}
        style={{
          width: '70px',
          marginLeft: '0.5rem',
        }}
      />
    </div>
  )
}


// Be sure to pass our updateMyData and the skipPageReset option
function Table({ columns, data, updateMyData, skipPageReset }) {
  const filterTypes = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      // Or, override the default text filter to use
      // "startWith"
      text: (rows, id, filterValue) => {
        return rows.filter(row => {
          const rowValue = row.values[id]
          return rowValue !== undefined
            ? String(rowValue)
                .toLowerCase()
                .startsWith(String(filterValue).toLowerCase())
            : true
        })
      },
    }),
    []
  )

  const defaultColumn = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      // Let's set up our default Filter UI
      Filter: DefaultColumnFilter,
      // And also our default editable cell
      Cell: EditableCell,
    }),
    []
  )

  // Use the state and functions returned from useTable to build your UI
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    prepareRow,
    page, // Instead of using 'rows', we'll use page,
    // which has only the rows for the active page

    // The rest of these things are super handy, too ;)
    canPreviousPage,
    canNextPage,
    pageOptions,
    pageCount,
    gotoPage,
    nextPage,
    previousPage,
    setPageSize,
    state: { pageIndex, pageSize, groupBy, expanded, filters, selectedRowIds },
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data,
      defaultColumn,
      filterTypes,
      // nestExpandedRows: true,
      initialState: { pageIndex: 2 },
      // updateMyData isn't part of the API, but
      // anything we put into these options will
      // automatically be available on the instance.
      // That way we can call this function from our
      // cell renderer!
      updateMyData,
      // We also need to pass this so the page doesn't change
      // when we edit the data, undefined means using the default
      autoResetPage: !skipPageReset,
    },
    useGroupBy,
    useFilters,
    useSortBy,
    useExpanded,
    usePagination,
    useRowSelect,
    hooks => {
      hooks.flatColumns.push(columns => [
        {
          id: 'selection',
          // Make this column a groupByBoundary. This ensures that groupBy columns
          // are placed after it
          groupByBoundary: true,
          // The header can use the table's getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps method
          // to render a checkbox
          Header: ({ getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps }) => (
            <div>
              <input type="checkbox" {...getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps()} />
            </div>
          ),
          // The cell can use the individual row's getToggleRowSelectedProps method
          // to the render a checkbox
          Cell: ({ row }) => (
            <div>
              <input type="checkbox" {...row.getToggleRowSelectedProps()} />
            </div>
          ),
        },
        ...columns,
      ])
    }
  )

  // Render the UI for your table
  return (
    <>
      <table {...getTableProps()}>
        <thead>
          {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
            <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>
                  <div>
                    {column.canGroupBy ? (
                      // If the column can be grouped, let's add a toggle
                      <span {...column.getGroupByToggleProps()}>
                        {column.isGrouped ? ' ' : ' '}
                      </span>
                    ) : null}
                    <span {...column.getSortByToggleProps()}>
                      {column.render('Header')}
                      {/* Add a sort direction indicator */}
                      {column.isSorted
                        ? column.isSortedDesc
                          ? ' '
                          : ' '
                        : ''}
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  {/* Render the columns filter UI */}
                  <div>{column.canFilter ? column.render('Filter') : null}</div>
                </th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {page.map(row => {
            prepareRow(row)
            return (
              <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                {row.cells.map(cell => {
                  return (
                    <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>
                      {cell.isGrouped ? (
                        // If it's a grouped cell, add an expander and row count
                        <>
                          <span {...row.getExpandedToggleProps()}>
                            {row.isExpanded ? '' : ''}
                          </span>{' '}
                          {cell.render('Cell', { editable: false })} (
                          {row.subRows.length})
                        </>
                      ) : cell.isAggregated ? (
                        // If the cell is aggregated, use the Aggregated
                        // renderer for cell
                        cell.render('Aggregated')
                      ) : cell.isRepeatedValue ? null : ( // For cells with repeated values, render null
                        // Otherwise, just render the regular cell
                        cell.render('Cell', { editable: true })
                      )}
                    </td>
                  )
                })}
              </tr>
            )
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      {/*
        Pagination can be built however you'd like.
        This is just a very basic UI implementation:
      */}
      <div className="pagination">
        <button onClick={() => gotoPage(0)} disabled={!canPreviousPage}>
          {'<<'}
        </button>{' '}
        <button onClick={() => previousPage()} disabled={!canPreviousPage}>
          {'<'}
        </button>{' '}
        <button onClick={() => nextPage()} disabled={!canNextPage}>
          {'>'}
        </button>{' '}
        <button onClick={() => gotoPage(pageCount - 1)} disabled={!canNextPage}>
          {'>>'}
        </button>{' '}
        <span>
          Page{' '}
          <strong>
            {pageIndex + 1} of {pageOptions.length}
          </strong>{' '}
        </span>
        <span>
          | Go to page:{' '}
          <input
            type="number"
            defaultValue={pageIndex + 1}
            onChange={e => {
              const page = e.target.value ? Number(e.target.value) - 1 : 0
              gotoPage(page)
            }}
            style={{ width: '100px' }}
          />
        </span>{' '}
        <select
          value={pageSize}
          onChange={e => {
            setPageSize(Number(e.target.value))
          }}
        >
          {[10, 20, 30, 40, 50].map(pageSize => (
            <option key={pageSize} value={pageSize}>
              Show {pageSize}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
      <pre>
        <code>
          {JSON.stringify(
            {
              pageIndex,
              pageSize,
              pageCount,
              canNextPage,
              canPreviousPage,
              groupBy,
              expanded: expanded,
              filters,
              selectedRowIds: selectedRowIds,
            },
            null,
            2
          )}
        </code>
      </pre>
    </>
  )
}

// Define a custom filter filter function!
function filterGreaterThan(rows, id, filterValue) {
  return rows.filter(row => {
    const rowValue = row.values[id]
    return rowValue >= filterValue
  })
}

// This is an autoRemove method on the filter function that
// when given the new filter value and returns true, the filter
// will be automatically removed. Normally this is just an undefined
// check, but here, we want to remove the filter if it's not a number
filterGreaterThan.autoRemove = val => typeof val !== 'number'

// This is a custom aggregator that
// takes in an array of values and
// returns the rounded median
function roundedMedian(values) {
  let min = values[0] || ''
  let max = values[0] || ''

  values.forEach(value => {
    min = Math.min(min, value)
    max = Math.max(max, value)
  })

  return Math.round((min + max) / 2)
}

function App() {
  const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: 'Document',
        columns: [
          {
            Header: 'Document Id',
            accessor: 'document_id',
            // Use a two-stage aggregator here to first
            // count the total rows being aggregated,
            // then sum any of those counts if they are
            // aggregated further
            //aggregate: ['sum', 'count'],
            //Aggregated: ({ cell: { value } }) => `${value} Names`,
          },
          {
            Header: 'CORS',
            accessor: 'doc_content.CORS',
            // Use our custom `fuzzyText` filter on this column
            filter: 'fuzzyText',
            // Use another two-stage aggregator here to
            // first count the UNIQUE values from the rows
            // being aggregated, then sum those counts if
            // they are aggregated further
          //  aggregate: ['sum', 'uniqueCount'],
          //  Aggregated: ({ cell: { value } }) => `${value} Unique Names`,
          },
          {
            Header: 'PM',
            accessor: '(doc_content) => doc_content.PM',
          //  Filter: SliderColumnFilter,
            //filter: 'equals',
            // Aggregate the average age of visitors
          //  aggregate: 'average',
          //  Aggregated: ({ cell: { value } }) => `${value} (avg)`,
          },
          {
            Header: 'FY XX Budget (Next Year\'s Budget)',
            accessor: 'doc_content.FY XX Budget (Next Year\'s Budget)',
          ////  Filter: NumberRangeColumnFilter,
        //filter: 'between',
            // Aggregate the sum of all visits
        //    aggregate: 'sum',
        //    Aggregated: ({ cell: { value } }) => `${value} (total)`,
          },
          {
            Header: 'Status',
            accessor: 'status',
            Filter: SelectColumnFilter,
            filter: 'includes',
          },
          {
            Header: 'Profile Progress',
            accessor: 'progress',
            Filter: SliderColumnFilter,
            filter: filterGreaterThan,
            // Use our custom roundedMedian aggregator
            aggregate: roundedMedian,
            Aggregated: ({ cell: { value } }) => `${value} (med)`,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
    []
  )

  const [data, setData] = React.useState(() => makeData(10000))
  const [originalData] = React.useState(data)

  // We need to keep the table from resetting the pageIndex when we
  // Update data. So we can keep track of that flag with a ref.
  const skipPageResetRef = React.useRef(false)

  // When our cell renderer calls updateMyData, we'll use
  // the rowIndex, columnId and new value to update the
  // original data
  const updateMyData = (rowIndex, columnId, value) => {
    // We also turn on the flag to not reset the page
    skipPageResetRef.current = true
    setData(old =>
      old.map((row, index) => {
        if (index === rowIndex) {
          return {
            ...row,
            [columnId]: value,
          }
        }
        return row
      })
    )
  }

  // After data chagnes, we turn the flag back off
  // so that if data actually changes when we're not
  // editing it, the page is reset
  React.useEffect(() => {
    skipPageResetRef.current = false
  }, [data])

  // Let's add a data resetter/randomizer to help
  // illustrate that flow...
  const resetData = () => {
    // Don't reset the page when we do this
    skipPageResetRef.current = true
    setData(originalData)
  }

  return (
    <Styles>
      <button onClick={resetData}>Reset Data</button>
      <Table
        columns={columns}
        data={data}
        updateMyData={updateMyData}
        skipPageReset={skipPageResetRef.current}
      />
    </Styles>
  )
}

export default App
```

I feel like there's something simple-ish i'm missing because i'm not yet familiar with the languages. Also, I need to make the text in column one a hyperlink to the associated record. Not sure about that one either...